# Crontab is running with errors

Tags: cron

I'm trying to run some scrapy spiders on my server with crontab programmatically. I tried several commands and I finally have this crontab which is not running and it's not giving me any helpful error either.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/root/
47 9,22 * * * cd Travel/lastsecond && scrapy crawl tours
```

This crontab is not working and in the `syslog` I get this:

```
Feb 13 09:47:01 d4bd CRON[18641]: (root) CMD (cd Travel/lastsecond && scrapy crawl tours)
Feb 13 09:47:01 d4bd CRON[18640]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

In the output, I'm getting this:

```
/bin/sh: 1: scrapy: not found
```

I have scrapy installed and the commands are working fine standalone.

Comment: I would use absolute paths in crontab and remove shebang. The file is not a Bash script as it suggests.

Comment: @Melebius is correct. "scrapy" needs a directory. `#!/bin/bash` what is that supposed to do in a cron?

Comment: @rinzwind it's for setting the path environment for cron, it's not possible to write it anotherway.

Comment: @Amirition no, you can not make cron a bash script. You can do `SHELL=/bin/sh` but not `#!/bin/bash`. That last one goes in your script itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scrapy` file cannot be found anywhere in `PATH` (see below). To find where it is located, use the following command in your interactive shell:

```
which scrapy
```

It will show its absolute path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/scrapy`. Put the absolute path to the crontab:

```
47 9,22 * * * cd Travel/lastsecond && /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl tours
```

### Regarding the `PATH` variable

The [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable is used to search for programs whenever you don’t specify the exact path on the command line or in a script. It is defined by the profile settings and by crontabs, too. It typically looks like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The example comes from my `/etc/crontab`. However, the value you provided in your crontab looks unusual…

```
PATH=/root/
```

Aren’t you trying to set the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) here?!

### Regarding shebang

[Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is the first line of many scripts. It specifies what interpreter shall interpret the file. It makes no sense in a crontab and you should remove it. Crontab is a *data* file for Cron, not a script.

Comment: Thanks, it works now by changing the `PATH` to `/usr/local/bin/` .

Answer (score 1):

Cron by default sends a mail to the user with the output of the commands it runs. But, as it says, no MAT (Mail Transfer Agent) is installed, so cron can't send the mail and discards the command output. You can redirect the output yourself, to a file or into the void (/dev/null) by changing your cron line to:

```
47 9,22 * * * cd Travel/lastsecond && scrapy crawl tours > outfile 2>&1
```

or

```
47 9,22 * * * cd Travel/lastsecond && scrapy crawl tours > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The second possibility is to install an MTA (sendmail, postfix or similar) - and configure it to handle local mail.

Or you could make sure that your script doesn't generate any output.

Comment: Why whould i need output for a script? It stores the errors ?

Comment: I can't tell if you need the output, but sometimes a script produces unexpected output or errors, which are nice to have for bug-hunting.

Comment: i updated the question with output file .

Comment: So it don't find your script ... what are the full path to scrapy ?